# Extract a field if it is accompanied by specific key-value pairs

Tags: json, jq

```
//test.json
{
"RED":
  [
    {
      "attr1": "aaaa",
      "attr2": "bbbb",
      "attr3": "cccc"
    },
    {
      "attr1": "aaaa",
      "attr2": "dddd",
      "attr3": "eeee"
    }
  ],
"WHITE":
  [
    {
      "attr1": "aaaa",
      "attr2": "bbbb",
      "attr3": "cccc"
    },
    {
      "attr1": "aaaa",
      "attr2": "dddd",
      "attr3": "eeee"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to get a value that meets (key=RED && attr1="aaaa" && attr2="bbbb")

So I have written jq command like this :

```
jq -r 'with_entries(select([.key] | inside(["RED"]))) | .[] | .[] | select(.attr1=="aaaa") | select(.attr2=="bbbb") | .attr3' test.json
```

this command works well. but I think that command is a little long.
How can I shorten the command without reducing readability?
(* This is my first time using JQ)

Comment: Is `RED` always going to be present? do you want it hardcoded or by dynamically selected?

Comment: @Inian I checked your answer. In the case I ask, RED is always present. I think your answer is very useful when i need to make a dynamic select. Thank you.

Comment: Next time, do clarify all the details beforehand. https://jqplay.org/s/WumRKjvHyn In case you wanted my answer (deleted) as reference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `with_entries` or multiple `select`s there. The following program does exactly the same thing and is way shorter.

```
.RED[] | select(.attr1 == "aaaa" and .attr2 == "bbbb") .attr3
```